# Why does IIFE function return undefined when value is passed instead of an Object?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript at the moment, Please look at this snippet of code:

I've here defined 3 Immediately Invoked Function Expressions. My expectation here is when I **console.log(controller)** it returns *undefined*. Can anyone please explain me, why does *controller IIFE* be able to return an Object but not a value?

```js
var budgetController = (function() {
  var x = 23;
  var add = function(a) {
    return x + a;
  }
  return {
    publicTest: function(b) {
      console.log(add(b));
    }
  }
})();

var UIController = (function() {

  //Some UI based Code

})();

var controller = (function(budgetCtrl, UICtrl) {
  var z = budgetCtrl.publicTest(5);
  return z;
})(budgetController, UIController);

console.log(controller); // Should return the value of 'z' [My Confusion/Misconception lies here]
console.log(budgetController); // Returns a Object
```

Comment: Because `publicTest` does not return anything (try using the `return` keyword)

Comment: *publicTest* returns *undefined* because you haven't included a return statement (or used an arrow function with an implicit return statement).

Comment: You need to distinguish "return" from "output". The two are very different, although the returned value can show up as output in the console. `console.log(...)` _outputs_ something, but _returns_ `undefined`. So does your `budgetCtrl.publicTest`. Thus... "`console.log(controller);` Should return the value of `z`"; no, it will _output_ the value of `z`. However, `z` happens to be `undefined`, because of this same terminological confusion; so `console.log(controller)` both _outputs_ and _returns_ `undefined` (though for different reasons).

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance, that worked!

Comment: @Amadan, thanks for all your effort in the explanation so quick.That really helped me understanding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are passing params to publicTest, you should return the value to store it in Z variable

```js
var budgetController = (function() {
  var x = 23;
  var add = function(a) {
    return x + a;
  };
  return {
    publicTest: function(b) {
      console.log(add(b));
      return add(b);
    }
  };
})();

var UIController = (function() {
  //Some UI based Code
})();

var controller = (function(budgetCtrl, UICtrl) {
  var z = budgetCtrl.publicTest(5);
  return z;
})(budgetController, UIController);

console.log(controller); // Should return the value of 'z' [My Confusion/Misconception lies here]
console.log(budgetController);
```